# I want the same function react in both way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which hidden/show a button when the `location.hash()`has been changed

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
     //some method to toggle a button
})
```

but i found that it won't execute when a user refresh the page instead of clicking the link to get in the individual page.

So i tried to put this in a `.ready()` but still

```
$(document).ready(function() {

         window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
         //some method to toggle a button
    })
        });
```

but it doesn't seem like it excute when the user refresh the page

Comment: if you want to *trigger* the function on a page reload, write the function as a real, named function (not an anonymous function in an event handling bind call) and then call that function directly.

Comment: The things is that i need it to execute in both way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function toggleButton() {
  // Some method to toggle a button
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", toggleButton);
window.addEventListener("hashchange", toggleButton);
```

Comment: Thanks, seem i should better stick with javascript instead of Jquery.

Comment: @anson920520 if you're already using jQuery for some reasons anywhere in your application, better use it, because $(document).ready() has fallbacks for browsers that don't support `DOMContentLoaded` event. So the first one will look like that: `$(document).ready(toggleButton);`.

Comment: Thanks again It seem these does support the browsers that i need to cover : http://caniuse.com/#tables , so i ll stick with js for now

Comment: although to be fair, there are no browsers that don't support that anymore, now that Microsoft's discontinued support for IE10 and below, with the exception of Windows Vista SP2 users, which is kind of too small a segment to care about.